# Error using range-based for loop - Eclipse CDT Luna

Tags: templates, c++11, for-loop, mingw, eclipse-luna

I am a beginner at C++ programming. I tried to write a very simple program that combines the use of templates, passing arrays as arguments to a function and a range-based for loop. This is the program that I wrote and compiled using the Eclipse Luna CDT software.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void display (T myArray[])
{
    int i = 1;
    for (T c : myArray)
    {
        cout << i << " element is " << c << endl;
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numArray[] {1, 2, 3};
    char charArray[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    display<int>(numArray);
    display<char>(charArray);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I save this file and build it, it says that there are errors on line 8, highlighting the range-based for loop. The compiler specifically states that " 'begin' and 'end' was not declared in this scope". The compiler is mingw-w64 and has been setup for C++11. How do I resolve this error?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a range based for loop you'll need to use `std::array` instead of C-style array. I modified your code so it works. Note that you'll need to pass `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void display (T myArray)
{
    int i = 1;
    for (auto c : myArray)
    {
        cout << i << " element is " << c << endl;
        ++i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> numArray {1, 2, 3};
    std::array<char, 3> charArray {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    display(numArray);
    display(charArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly when i added your changes to the program. Could you tell me why a C-style array doesn't work? Is it because it is not compatible with C++11 additions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RamSidharthNair Range based for loops use "begin" and "end" iterators. C-style arrays don't have them so you need to use a container that does, e.g. std::array, std::vector etc.

Comment: @RamSidharthNair range for loops work perfectly fine with C arrays. What you called "myArray" was a pointer though.

Answer (score -2):

in c++ there is no "for each" like in other languages as php etc...

so you have to tell the function where the array ends, because if you give an array to the function, it only gets an pointer of the starting postition...

this should work for you:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void display (T myArray[], int arraysize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize ;i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << " element is " << myArray[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numArray[] = {1, 2, 3};
    char charArray[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    display<int>(numArray, 3);
    display<char>(charArray, 3);

    return 0;
```

Comment: I was also surprised to see the ranged for syntax, but then I googled and found that till C++ 11 it DOES exist in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Range based for loops were added in C++11.

Comment: Then it would maybe fix the problem, not to give the beginning pointer of the array, but a reference of the array (as done in the example of your link)?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't really know because I haven't seen this syntax before. About the example - it demonstrates iterator and not array, so I'm not sure what is the behavior in case of arrays.